# Regular expression for matching blocks delimited by separators of variable type

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to cleanse some email messages from automatically appended chunks of text. Each one of those chunks is enclosed by a pair of separators (single or multiple lines). I need a regular expression that will match anything between such separators so that I can remove it.

Here is some text that illustrates the problem and shows all the weird cases that need to be accounted for:

```
This is some text that should not be matched. As you can see, it is not enclosed
by separator lines.

===========================================================
This part should be matched as it is between two separator lines. Note that the
opening and closing separators are composed of the exact same number of the same
character.
===========================================================
This block should not be matched as it is not enclosed by its own separators,
but rather the closing separator of the previous block and the opening 
separator of the next block.
===========================================================
It is tricky to distinguish between an enclosed and non-enclosed blocks, because
sometimes a matching pair of separators appears to be legal, while it is really
the closing separator of the previous block and the opening separator of the
next one (e.g. the block obove this one).
===========================================================
==================================
=====
This block is enclosed by multiline separators.
==================================
=====
Some more text that should not be matched by the regex.
***************************************



A separator can be a different character, for example the asterisk.


***************************************
***************************************
*******************
Another example of a multiline separated block.
***************************************
*******************

>Even more text not to be matchedby the regex. This time, preceeded by a
>variable number of '>'.
>>__________________________________________
>>And another type of separator. The block is now also a part of a reply section
>>of the email.
>>__________________________________________
```

Note that there is no recursion to be handled here - a block is never inside of another block.
I've been trying work this out for a while now, but I am not experienced enough when it comes to regex. I do not know how to make the expression "remember" what the opening separator was.

Right now my solution will produce incorrect matches for a block like this:

```
=========================
text text
text
*************************
```

I would really appreciate some help on this. I am working in Ruby, but will work through different types of syntax if required.

Comment: This is impossible per se, because _“A separator can be a different character”_ line must be treated as matched according to your rules _and_ must be treated as not matched according to your explanation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your comment. The expression should match blocks enclosed by two identical separators (in terms of the character used, length and number of lines used by the separator itself). There are different types of separators that enclose the blocks, as illustrated above.

Comment: There is no magical intelligence that might tell the regular expression engine that _“A separator can be a different character...”_ line **that is enclosed by two identical separators, consisting of 39 asterisks each**, should not be filtered out.

Comment: I have two suggestions. First, assign a variable to your string, say with a [heredoc](https://zaiste.net/heredoc_in_ruby/): `str<==END` at the beginning and `END` after the last line. That way the variable (`str`) can be referenced in answers. Secondly, while the use of a regular expression seems likely, simply state what you want as a result and show the desired result for your example. In general, whenever you give an example, ensure that everything is a valid Ruby object, assign a variable to all input objects, show the desired result and make the example as succinct as possible.

Comment: Further to my last comment, you state, "I need a regular expression that will match anything between such separators so that I can remove it.", I suggest you make the objective, "I wish to remove several blocks of text, according to rules that are given in the following example.". Then show your desired result, which is your original text with parts removed. This would help answer questions that I--and no doubt others--have about what you wish to do. One specific question: must lines that bracket a block be of a certain length?

Comment: Even if you can do this with regex, I wouldn't. It looks like you need a more robust parser. Separators inside replies and multiline separators look especially tricky to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `((.)(?:\2)+)(?:\n(\2+))?\n.+?\n\1(?:(?:\n\3))?`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HRrjYu/2)

Please note that I have added 2 restrictions around the multiline separators:

1. only 2 lines in the separator
2. separator on the second line is same as the first line

Let me know if these restrictions are not needed.

Comment: @Jan Parzydlo I'll add the detailed explanation, if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [backward capture](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing) should do:

```
input.gsub(/(?<sep>\W{40,}).*?(\k<sep>)/m, "\n")
```